# codename1 localization don't work

Tags: java, codenameone

I have made a new resourcebundle in the theme.res. I have 2 languages (en, da).
I've written this code:

```
public void init(Object context) {
    theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

    String lang = L10NManager.getInstance().getLanguage();
    try {
        if (lang != null) {
            lang = lang.toLowerCase();
            switch (lang) {
                case "da":
                    Map<String, String> localMap = theme.getL10N("local", "da");
                    UIManager.createInstance().setBundle(localMap);
                    System.out.println("Entries: " + localMap.size());
                    break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I run the code it does get the bundle and the localMap does keep the 'da' landuage entries as it should.
But nothing happens. The GUI texts are just the keys.
Is there something I miss here?

Comment: The Shai's answer is correct. I also suggest you to use Log.p("...") instead of System.out.println("...").

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
UIManager.createInstance().setBundle(localMap);
```

You should have used:

```
UIManager.getInstance().setBundle(localMap);
```